# LWC querySelector with multiple conditions

Tags: lightning-web-components, queryselector

I have a few `lightning-input` in my for:each iterator like code below:

```
<template for:each={records} for:item="record">
    <lightning-input data-id={record.Id}
                     name="inputA"
                     label="inputA"
                     value={record.value}
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-input data-id={record.Id} 
                     name="inputB"
                     label="inputB" 
                     value={record.value}
    </lightning-input>
</template>
```

I want to get the element which has inputA as its name and targetRecord.Id as its data-id, like:

`let targetEl = this.template.querySelector("[data-id="+targetRecordId+"][name=inputA]");`

and do something like getting its value. But those multiple conditions don't work. It returns null.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two selectors together in a single `querySelectorAll` like this:

```
let id = 'yourid';
let name = 'inputA';
this.template.querySelectorAll(`[data-id=${id}][data-name=${name}]`);
```

**ALSO** you need to use another `data` attribute - shown above as `data-name`, because the `name` attribute becomes internal to the component.

Finally make sure all data is rendered before you try to access these components.

(I've used backticks template syntax to build the selection string in a more readable way.)

Here is the markup that I can guarantee the above selector syntax finds:

```
 <lightning-input   data-id="input1"
                 data-name="inputA" 
                 name="inputA"
                 label="inputA"
                 value="test1">
 </lightning-input>
 <lightning-input data-id="input1"
                 data-name="inputB" 
                 name="inputB"
                 label="inputB"
                 value="test1">
 </lightning-input>
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. I've tried querySelectorAll with [0] as there must be only one matching element but it returns undefined.

Comment: @theWoodpecker you nees to use the (.) value at the end without paranthesis.

Comment: ```let selected = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-id="${id}"][name="${name}"]`).value;```

Comment: So, have you tried this? I created a component and tested this and can verify that it works.

Comment: Hi, thank you, ```this.template.querySelectorAll(`[data-id=${id}][data-name=${name}]`)[0]```  works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of relying on accessing the DOM, what I suggest is that you always try and keep a property which has all your updated data in your JS function, this way, you can always access it through JS using a filter, or find method, which is much cleaner and easier to maintain. Keep your DOM reactive to changes in your props instead.

you would have to add change handlers to each of your input components, and in your handler, update your prop accordingly, so you can later access the data, and ensure it is up to date.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tips. I'll keep it in mind :)

Comment: its also easier to do unit testing with this approach, additionally, if there are changes to lwc components that could affect how they are rendered, this can "break" your query selectors. Happy coding!